# Intento cargar 4 mil registros en un Datatable y demora varios segundos

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, datatables

Mi problema es que al cargar los registros de la BD en el datatable se demora varios segundos, eh mirado que se pueden mostrar solo los datos que necesitas ver y a partir de ahí hacer una petición para los demás datos pero no comprendo como se hace eso mi código es el siguiente:

Datatable:

```
var table = $('#tableProveedores').DataTable({
                    bDeferRender: true,
                    responsive: true,
                    columnDefs: [{
                        // "targets": 7,
                        "orderable": false
                    }],
                    scrollX:        true,
                    data: response.provider,
                    columns: [
                        {data: "nombre"},
                        {
                            "render": function (data, type, row, meta){
                                var $select = $('<select class="form-control" id="tipo"><option id="basico" value="0">Basico</option><option value="1">Plata</option><option value="2">Oro</option><option value="3">Diamante</option></select>');
                                $select.find('option[value="'+row.tipo_cuenta+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
                                return $select[0].outerHTML;
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "render": function (data, type, row, meta){
                                var $select = $('<select class="form-control" id="estado"><option value="0">Desactivado</option><option value="1">Pendiente</option><option value="2">Activo</option></select>');
                                $select.find('option[value="'+row.activo+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
                                return $select[0].outerHTML;
                            }
                        },
                        {data: "usuario"},
                        {data: "correo"},
                        {data: "contacto_celular"},
                        {"render":
                            function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return (row["localizacion_estado"] + ', ' + row["localizacion_pais"]);
                            }
                        },
                        {data: "fecha_creacion"},
                    ],
                    language: {
                        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
                    }
                });
```

Controller:

```
public function extraerProveedores() {
    if($_POST) {
        $data = $this->proveedor->getAllAdmin();

        return $this->output->set_content_type("application/json")
                ->set_status_header(200)
                ->set_output(json_encode(['success' => true, 'provider' => $data]));
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function getAllAdmin()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT proveedor.* ,usuario.correo, usuario.usuario, usuario.activo ,fecha_creacion FROM proveedor INNER JOIN usuario USING(id_usuario) ;';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->result();
}
```

Busqué ya en la documentación oficial de Datatables pero no logro comprender como se puede optimizar la carga de datos.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar ReactJS, VueJS o AngularJS son librerías y/o Framework que son dedicados para renderizar muchos registros a la vez, con jquery puedes hacerlo más fácil, pero no esperes muy buenos resultados con poco esfuerzo.

Comment: @MerlingSamuelSobalvarro revisaré las librerías que me comentas para ver si puedo lograr que la carga de datos sea más eficiente, gracias por el tip.

Comment: Te recomiendo la paginacion, porque aunque utilices un framework con vuejs u otro tardará ya que la transacción de grandes cantidades de datos también tarda, más o menos dependiendo de la velocidad de internet del usuario

Comment: @JimyHendrixFalcónCárdenas te refieres a hacer la paginación desde el controlador para que me mande los datos ya paginados a la vista?

Comment: Exacto, es la mejor manera de no sobrecargar tu propio servidor y no dar una mala experiencia al usuario

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que una buena parte del consumo de tiempo (y de recursos en tu pc) radique en los select que estas creando en el render. Piensa que si estas sacando 4000 registros, le estás diciendo a js que cree 8000 selects, ya que tienes 2 selects por registro. Esto creará una carga importante.

Lo que puedes hacer para optimizarlo sería (por ejemplo) lo siguiente:

- En esos campos simplemente muestra el valor que deseas (texto plano: simplemente el valor de "row.tipo_cuenta").
- Create una función que te genere de forma dinámica un select con los options que quieras (pasaselos por parámetro y así te vale para ambos selects).
- Crea un evento on.click para que al pulsar en alguno de esos dos campos, se llame a la función "crear_select" e insertas el select en cuestión en esa celda.

Nota: tendrás que crear otras funciones de eventos focusout/change/... para que vuelva a guardar el valor seleccionado en tu datatables y vuelva a mostrar sólo el texto del option seleccionado.

Nota2: otra forma es que en lugar de hacerlo con eventos click y focusout/change/..., lo hagas añadiendo una/dos columna(s) más al datatables que sea por ejemplo: "editar". Al hacer click en esa celda (pones un icono, por ejemplo), haces lo que te he comentado antes: crear dos selects invocando la función "crear_select", los insertas y a la vez sustituyes tu icono "editar" por un icono "guardar". Creas un evento para que al hacer click en el icono de guardar, se vuelvan a mostrar solo los textos de los options seleccionados.

Con esto reducirias el número de selects de 8000 a 2

Comment: Comprendo lo que me dices y suena bien la verdad es que si es bastante la carga de todos esos select pero no pensé que en parte se debería a eso, trataré de realizar los ajustes que me recomiendas a ver si se agiliza un poco mas la carga de los datos gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @MiguelMota de nada. Ya nos comentas si te ha servido o si hay que seguir investigando. Un saludo Miguel.

Comment: claro que si, en cuanto pueda aplicar los cambios trataré de informarte si se solucionó el problema o no. Saludos :D

Comment: Se habrá solucionado? Como lo habría hecho?